# why do I need to pull request?

Tags: git

I am working on `player_json_data` branch and for the sake of the example the `master` branch was where the `search_players_algorithm` branch was.I want to update the master so I did

```
git checkout master    
git reset --hard player_json_data
```

and then the `master` is updated immediately. I did `git push` and the master is up to date.
When and why do I need to make a pull request ? I always thought that when you want to update the master you need to create a PR from the feature branch and then after the PR is approved the feature branch is merged into the master. Why in this example I don't need to use one? When and why PR is used ?

[image]

Comment: In a group environment you *never* want everyone to have the ability to `git push` to `master`. Pull requests are a way to have a second reviewer look over your changes before doing a merge into the target branch (merge, fast-forward, etc).

Comment: if I work alone is it okay to to what I did ? If I want to embrace that method what do I need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Just like @CoryKramer said, Pull Requests are needed in a team environment.

> if I work alone is it okay to to what I did ?

*Well it depends*, if you are trying to merge two branches, you may think of doing a PR, but again, it is totally subjective and depends on your preference.

I don't use PRs on my personal project because *I* generally have an idea of what I am doing. ;)

**TL;DR:** PRs are a measure to prevent *anyone* from merging garbage into your code and maintain an organised & fluid project flow. Many organisations(in fact, Git and Linux do this) prefer submitting "patches" or the changes you made via a *mailing list*. [This](https://lore.kernel.org/git/) is how Git's mailing list looks like.

Best.